# Hierarchical filtering of a data set

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, filtering

I want to filter my dataset based on several criteria (mainly disease type and location).
I have decided that there are no certain types of disease for certain locations (pancreatic disease can only be an infection - This is why a made only`Total` for choice when Organ=Pancreas -. I know that's not realistic, it's just a hypothesis). So I want to do hierarchical filtering (The variable `Organ` is at the top of the hierarchy, and `TypeOfDisease` at the bottom). I'm looking for the shortest way (A kind of recursive if-statement) to compute the if statements without combining all the categories two by two.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
TypeOfDisease<-c(rep("Infection",12),rep("Cancer",5),rep("Infection",14),
                 rep("Cancer",9),rep("Infection",8),rep("Cancer",7),rep("Infection",15),rep("Cancer",0),
                 rep("Infection",12),rep("Cancer",18))
Organ<-c(rep("Oesophage",17),rep("Stomach",23),rep("Lung",15),rep("Pancreas",15),rep("Liver",30))
data<-data.frame(TypeOfDisease,Organ)
addmargins(table(data$TypeOfDisease,dataF$Organ))

ui<-fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Organ","Select the organ",
                  choices = c("Total",levels(data$Organ))),
      
      uiOutput("ui"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      fluidRow(
        column(5,tableOutput("table")),
        column(7,
               
               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("matrix")),
               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Nrow"))
               )
      )
      
      
      
      )
  )
  
)


server<-function(input,output){
  
  
  output$ui<-renderUI(
    
    switch (input$Organ,
            
      "Total" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                      choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
      "Oesophage" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
      "Stomach" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
      "Lung" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
      "Pancreas" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                choices = c("Total")),
      "Liver" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
    )
  )
  
  dataFilter<-reactive({
    
    if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Total"){
      data
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Oesophage"){
        data%>%filter(Organ=="Oesophage")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Stomach"){
       data%>%filter(Organ=="Stomach")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Lung"){
      data%>%filter(Organ=="Lung")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Pancreas"){
      data%>%filter(Organ=="Pancreas")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Liver"){
      data%>%filter(Organ=="Liver")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Total"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Oesophage"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection"&Organ=="Oesophage")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Stomach"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection"&Organ=="Stomach")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Lung"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection"&Organ=="Lung")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Pancreas"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection"&Organ=="Pancreas")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Infection"&input$Organ=="Liver"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Infection"&Organ=="Liver")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Cancer"&input$Organ=="Oesophage"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"&Organ=="Oesophage")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Cancer"&input$Organ=="Stomach"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"&Organ=="Stomach")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Cancer"&input$Organ=="Lung"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"&Organ=="Lung")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Cancer"&input$Organ=="Pancreas"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"&Organ=="Pancreas")
    }else if(input$TypeOfDis=="Cancer"&input$Organ=="Liver"){
      data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"&Organ=="Liver")
      }else{(data%>%data%>%filter(TypeOfDisease=="Cancer"))}
        
        
  })
  output$table<-renderTable ({dataFilter()})
  output$matrix<-renderPrint({addmargins(table(data$TypeOfDisease,dataF$Organ))})
  output$Nrow<-renderPrint({nrow(dataFilter())})
  
}



shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can filter like this

```
  dataFilter2<-reactive({
    
    if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Total"){
      data
    }else {
      if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"){
        data[data$Organ==input$Organ,]
      }else data[data$TypeOfDisease==input$TypeOfDis & data$Organ==input$Organ ,]
    } 
    
  })
```